# Primarily only use DI for 'external' dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I used to think that if you ever saw the following in code it was BAD:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
```

all your objects should be newed up by a IOC container but from a question i asked yesterday it appears my thinking was wrong.

From my understanding now you only need to worry about *external* dependencies. You are free to new up all the internal classes to your hearts content just don't be newing up any external dependencies. In that regard you only need to create interfaces to your objects at the boundaries/edges (services) of your classes or however you expect clients are going to be communicating with you. Does that sound about right?

Comment: DI/IOC is useful in both circumstances, however don't get stuck on applying a design philosophy to *everything*, if it doesn't make sense architecturally, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the distinction between [newables and injectables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/). Injectables are the components in our application that have behavior. Newables are about anything else, such as primitives, strings, DTOs, entities, messages, commands, etc. Those newables present the runtime data of your system, and you push that runtime data through the object graph of injectables using method calls. Those injectables are created by your composition root (and therefore optionally your container), while newables can be created by application code. So if you follow Misko Hevery, having `new` statements in your code is fine, as long as they are 'newables'.

If you follow the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), you know that "High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.". Neither the definition in wikipedia, nor the original article from Robert C. Martin however clearly define what a module is. As I see it, it could be a class, or sometimes a group of classes that together form a module. What the dependency principle says is that such module should not depend on other modules. This is probably what you call 'external dependencies'. So within the module, everything can be highly cohesive, while the module has low coupling to other modules.

Another way to look at it is from a testability perspective. Even if you have a module consisting of multiple classes, if the coupling inside that module hinders testability, you'd better refactor that module to make it testable. The best way to do this is by dependency injection. This can result into having dependency injection within one component, for the sake of making that component testable.

A last way to look at this is from the perspective of maintainability. There are usually common locations where you would like to add cross-cutting concerns. For instance, all business operations should typically be wrapped inside a transaction, permissions should be checked, audit logs need to be written, etc, etc. For your application to stay maintainable, you need interception points where you can easily apply those cross-cutting concerns. You would typically see these interception points around component boundaries, but if you detect places within components where cross-cutting concerns need to be applied, that will be a place to start using interfaces.